# Issue with function multi_items from package SEMinR

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I have a little problem. I have some indicators that do not load enough on their constructs and I would like to delete them. In the SEMinR package documentation, there doesn't seem any solution to this issue.

Here is the script for one of those constructs :

`composite("LMX", multi_items("LMX", 1:6))`
Items 3 and 5 should be deleted. How do I rewrite the code for multi_items?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but does not `composite("LMX", multi_items("LMX", c(1,2,4,6))` work? Also, the edit queue is full, and I am unable to edit, but 'sem' tag refers to search engine marketing... if you specify more clearly 'structural equation model' as tag, you enhance the change of getting more answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got you want to delete some indicators from measurement model.
Usually the idea is to set a new formula/model, and run the analysis (again)...
So, replacing that part of the code with:

```
composite("LMX", multi_items("LMX", c(1,2,4,6))
```

should work...